# Count the number of rows in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Hello i'm trying to get the total number of rows with this query doing  Count(s.Folio) but i'm getting this result and i need to get 3 in this case
[image: Result]

```
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
                                   s.InstitucionOrigenId
                              ) AS Consecutivo,
            s.InstitucionDestino,
            s.InstitucionOrigen,
            @FechaAtencion      FechaAtencion,
            COUNT(s.Folio)      TotalDocumentos,
            DetalleFolio.Estado,
            s.Folio,
            s.FormaEntrega,
            s.FechaPresentacion,
            s.NumeroCuenta,
            s.NumeroReferencia,
            s.Importe,
            s.Divisa,
            DetalleFolio.FechaVencimiento

        FROM
            doc.vDocumento                                   s
            CROSS APPLY ope.fObtenerDetalleFolio(s.Folio, 1) DetalleFolio

        WHERE
            DetalleFolio.Estado = CASE
                                      WHEN @EnBancoOrigen = 1
                                          THEN 'RECIBIDO'
                                      ELSE
                                          'ATENDIDO'
                                  END

        GROUP BY
            s.InstitucionOrigenId,
            s.InstitucionDestino,
            s.InstitucionOrigen,
            DetalleFolio.Estado,
            s.Folio,
            s.FormaEntrega,
            s.FechaPresentacion,
            s.NumeroCuenta,
            s.NumeroReferencia,
            s.Importe,
            s.Divisa,
            DetalleFolio.FechaVencimiento
```

i'm kinda new to sql what am i missing? thanks in advance

Comment: did u tried the same query by removing row_number column ?

Comment: yeah but i'm getting the same result

Comment: is that column s.InstitucionOrigenId  has duplicate rows

Comment: Try and use : ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by s.InstitucionOrigenId ORDER BY
                                   s.InstitucionOrigenId
                              ) AS Consecutivo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `group by` and replace the count column with:

```
count(*) over () TotalDocumentos
```